# Track LocationChanged and SizeChanged usercontrol events when the control is inside a panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dwm

I'm developing a user-control that I use to register/draw a DWM thumbnail that must cover the control surface, see an example:

[image]

I overriden the **OnLocationChanged** and **OnSizeChanged** event invocators in my usercontrol derived class to be aware when the control location or size is changed and so I can fix/renew the DWM thumbnail position and size, however, these events are not fired when my control is located inside a container control like for example a **Panel**, so, In this image below you can see what happens when my control is inside a Panel and then I resize the parent form to the right side:

[image]

...as I can't determine that the user-control location has changed relatively to the parent form, the DWM thumbnail location remains the same as before. The same would happen with its size, when resizing the form.

Which would be the good approach to solve this issue?. The **LocationChanged** and **SizeChanged** events of my user-control does not seem useful to really track those changes relatively to the container parent and/or parent form...

Comment: @Reza Aghaei I did what you said, I overriden the OnPaint method but it is not called when I resize the form

Comment: @Reza Aghaei no, I'll explain you better: there is no kind of paint logic in my control, I just use DWM API (DwmRegisterThumbnail function) to register a thumnbail and for that thumbnail I specify the location and size of my user control (so the Windows API manages to draw the thumbnail over the surface of my control), I renew the DWM thumbnail location and size in OnSizeChanged and OnLocationChanged methods (by calling the DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties function).

Comment: If the form moving is what creates the problem, then use the LocationChanged event for the form, or preferably the OnLocationChanged override.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks but I need a solution that can be done within the inherited UserControl class.

Comment: The UserControl has access to a ParentForm property.  You can hook up to the event that way.

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you, I solved it that way. Now I'm worried about a way to detect parent form changes to be aware about whwn I need to reassociate the event-handlers for the new parent form (**OnParentChanged** method seems only triggers for the **Parent** property not for the **ParentForm**). Anyway, I think it is fine now.

Comment: It's pretty rare to move controls to a different form.

Comment: Just trying to figure and prevent all the possible scenarios that can cause a malfunction of my control. But yes, its rare, that's why I thought its just fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Use an anchor, *left, top, right and bottom*, to your *usercontrol*.